# mysql php return data

Tags: php, mysql

Every time i try to print a value i get "ArrayArray"
So this is what i got:

```
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {   
        echo "<br>";
        echo "Usuario: " . $row.["Usuario"]. " - Password: " . $row.["Password"]. "- Privilegios: " . $row.["Nivel"]. "- Email: " . $row.["Email"]. "<br>";
        echo "Usuario: " . $row.['Usuario']. " - Password: " . $row.['Password']. "- Privilegios: " . $row.['Nivel']. "- Email: " . $row.['Email']. "<br>";
        var_dump($row.[]);
        $user=$row.["Usuario"];
        $pass=$row.["Password"];
        $lvl=$row.["Nivel"];
        $email=$row.["Email"];
        echo "<br> Usuario: " . $user. " - Password: " . $pass. "- Privilegios: " . $lvl. "- Email: " . $email. "<br>";
        $user=$row.['Usuario'];
        $pass=$row.['Password'];
        $lvl=$row.['Nivel'];
        $email=$row.['Email'];
        echo "Usuario: " . $user. " - Password: " . $pass. "- Privilegios: " . $lvl. "- Email: " . $email. "<br>";
    }
```

I wasnt sure which was the right way to use it so i did it a couple times.
the query string:

Select * from Usuarios where Usuario='User' and Password='Pass' LIMIT 1

output:

```
Usuario: ArrayArray - Password: ArrayArray- Privilegios: ArrayArray- Email: ArrayArray
Usuario: ArrayArray - Password: ArrayArray- Privilegios: ArrayArray- Email: ArrayArray
string(10) "ArrayArray" 
Usuario: ArrayArray - Password: ArrayArray- Privilegios: ArrayArray- Email: ArrayArray
Usuario: ArrayArray - Password: ArrayArray- Privilegios: ArrayArray- Email: ArrayArray
Usuario: ArrayArray - Password: ArrayArray- Privilegios: ArrayArray- Email: ArrayArray
Usuario: ArrayArray - Password: ArrayArray- Privilegios: ArrayArray- Email: ArrayArray
```

Query result when run on db:

```
Usuario Password Nivel Email
User    Pass     3     email@this.com
```

i check 8 times all column names and data compare and its all correct. Any idea why this is, how can i solve it or how else can i read a mysql return table? Thanks!
Ps: var_dump($row.["colName"]) returns "string(10) ArrayArray"

Comment: Sidenote: Showing passwords is a bad thing, and you seem to be storing them as plain text also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace all instances of `$row.["X"]` with `$row["X"]`

`$row` is an array.

Lookup the correct way to access keys in an array.

Also, enabling error reporting will reveal:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in ... some file at some line

You're trying to concatenate two arrays and print them. (in php>5.4, `["X"]`  is an array containing one element)

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php) link on enabling error messages.
And [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php) link on php arrays.

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: `$row.["Email"]` etc. you mean more like: *"Replace all instances of"* `$row.["X"]` to `$row["X"]` ;-) `X = their_column`.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, yep! was gonna do that but i was gathering some helping links

Comment: That's a big "10-4" Alex ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your code should like this:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {   
        echo "<br>";
        echo "Usuario: " . $row["Usuario"]. " - Password: " . $row["Password"]. "- Privilegios: " . $row["Nivel"]. "- Email: " . $row["Email"]. "<br>";
        echo "Usuario: " . $row['Usuario']. " - Password: " . $row['Password']. "- Privilegios: " . $row['Nivel']. "- Email: " . $row['Email']. "<br>";
        var_dump($row[]);
        $user=$row["Usuario"];
        $pass=$row["Password"];
        $lvl=$row["Nivel"];
        $email=$row["Email"];
        echo "<br> Usuario: " . $user. " - Password: " . $pass. "- Privilegios: " . $lvl. "- Email: " . $email. "<br>";
        $user=$row['Usuario'];
        $pass=$row['Password'];
        $lvl=$row['Nivel'];
        $email=$row['Email'];
        echo "Usuario: " . $user. " - Password: " . $pass. "- Privilegios: " . $lvl. "- Email: " . $email. "<br>";
    }
```

Change   $row.["Usuario"]   to this $row["Usuario"]
No need of . (Dot) after $row
Remove all Dots after $row